# Checked as default --> The user must confirm the account cancellation via e-mail.

Tags: users

How can I checked as default the value **Require e-mail confirmation to cancel account.** 
It is unchecked as default :(

I tried to edit user.module editing this line **'#default_value' => TRUE,** but it doesn't work

```
  // Allow to send the account cancellation confirmation mail.
  $form['user_cancel_confirm'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Require e-mail confirmation to cancel account.'),
    '#default_value' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('When enabled, the user must confirm the account cancellation via e-mail.'),
```

Comment: I did that, and it worked for me. Could it be you're looking at a wrong page?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [never modifying core or contrib modules](https://www.drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core).

Instead, the right practice here is to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360).

So, configure a little module and put the following code in it:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //get your form id
  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'MY FORM ID':
      $form['user_cancel_confirm']['#default_value'] = 1;
      break;
    case 'OTHER FORM ID':
      //do sthing
      break;
    //...
  }
}
```